# How to manage multiple skin of css with the same structure but different colors?

Tags: css, sass, less

I need three skins that only have different colors

How can I create them so that the default file restructuring is applied automatically to other files?

```
<div class="test">
  Test
</div>
```

defaultVariables.scss:

```
$background: #f00;
```

default.scss:

```
@import "defaultVariables.scss";

.test{
    background: $background;
}
```

default.css:

```
.test{
    background: #f00;
}
```

darkVariables.scss:

```
$background: #000;
```

dark.scss:

```
@import "default.scss";
@import "darkVariables.scss";
```

dark.css: Expected output -> background: #000;

```
.test{
    background: #f00;
}
```

lightVariables.scss:

```
$background: #fff;
```

light.scss:

```
@import "default.scss";
@import "light.scss";
```

light.css: Expected output -> background: #fff;

```
.test{
    background: #f00;
}
```

Comment: What mechanism decides which scss file is loaded to the page?

Comment: Does css these days actually allow `//`-style commenting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must define `_variable.scss` and write all colors in this file:

```css
//colors
$background:red;
$primary-color:#b22930;
$second-color:#dd4420;

//and then define again variables in dark mode for example:

body[data-theme="dark"]{
//colors
$background:#333;
$primary-color:#555;
$second-color:#888;
}
```

Or check this link:
[link for example](https://codepen.io/abaykan/embed/oNvamJX?height=565&theme-id=0&default-tab=html%2Cresult&user=abaykan&slug-hash=oNvamJX&pen-title=Dark%2FLight%20Mode%20Switch%20with%20CSS%20Variables&name=cp_embed_2)

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way is to use css capabilities:

```js
function toggleSkin() {
   document
   .getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
   .classList
   .toggle("dark");
}
```

```css
:root {
    --back-color: #fff;
    --color: #000;
}

html.dark {
    --back-color: #000;
    --color: #fff;
}

body {
  background: var(--back-color);
  color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Test
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Toggle skin" onclick="toggleSkin()" />
</body>
</html>
```